# Offset with an array of unknown length

Tags: php-5.6

I building an array from an other.
I have the keys and the values but I don't know how deep can be my new array

I was using the eval function but SONAR refuses it. So I have to find an other way.

```
$splitpair[0] = array("key1", "key2", "...", "keyN");
$splitpair[1] = "val1";
$returnArray[$splitpair[0]] = $splitpair[1];
```

I want my returned array like this: `$returnArray[key1][key2][...][keyN] = "val1";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over your indexes and move a reference to point to the last nested array

`

```
$returnArray = [];

$buffer = &$returnArray;//buffer points to $returnArray

$array = array('key1','key2','key3');

foreach($array as $index){
    if(!(isset($buffer[$index])&&is_array($buffer[$index]))){
        $buffer[$index]=[]; //if $buffer[$index] is not an array, initialize it
    }
    $buffer=&$buffer[$index];//buffer points to the last nested array ($returnArray['key1']['key2']....[$index])
}

$buffer='val1';

var_dump($returnArray);
```

`